# How to get full referrer url

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, asp.net, html

I am using ASP.Net.

I want to get full referrer URL when I get to website from:

```
https://www.google.co.il/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&rlz=1C1CHEU_iwIL457IL457&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=%D7%90%D7%9C%D7%9B%D7%A1%D7%A0%D7%93%D7%A8%20%D7%90%D7%99%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%A2%D7%99%D7%9D
```

I can only get from header `www.google.co.il`, can I get the full URL?

Comment: If `Request.UrlReferrer` only returns the root url, then no; you clearly can't in that case.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. You can navigate user to previous page with

```
window.history.back();
```

but you will not know what url it was. You can get only this:

```
document.referrer
```

I know, it's not full query with url, but it's referrer.